# Laravel - query builder add or subtract duration field in months from started datetime field to calculate ended

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-5

I have a database that contains two tables:

```
describe project;
+------------+------------------+------+-----+-------------------+-------+
| Field      | Type             | Null | Key | Default           | Extra |
+------------+------------------+------+-----+-------------------+-------+
| id         | int(10) unsigned | NO   | PRI | NULL              |       |
| name       | varchar(45)      | NO   |     | NULL              |       |
| started_at | datetime         | NO   |     | NULL              |       |
| created_at | datetime         | NO   |     | CURRENT_TIMESTAMP |       |
+------------+------------------+------+-----+-------------------+-------+


describe proposal;
+------------------+------------------+------+-----+-------------------+----------------+
| Field            | Type             | Null | Key | Default           | Extra          |
+------------------+------------------+------+-----+-------------------+----------------+
| id               | int(10) unsigned | NO   | PRI | NULL              | auto_increment |
| ...                                                                                   |
| ...                                                                                   |
| duration         | int(10) unsigned | NO   |     | NULL              |                |
+------------------+------------------+------+-----+-------------------+----------------+
```

I want to get the current running projects. The `project` is still running if it's in the `duration` (in months). The condition should be `started_at + duration >= now`, in other way it can be `started_at >= now - duration`. So, I wrote Mysql query:

```
select p.id FROM portaldb.proposal p
join portaldb.project r on r.id = p.id
where date_add(r.started_at, interval p.duration month) >= now();
```

and it worked correctly, but when I tried to use the query builder in Laravel (I'm newbie), I wrote it as:

```
$proj= DB::table('proposal')
       ->join('project', 'proposal.id', '=', 'project.id')
       ->where('project.started_at', '>=', Carbon::now()->subMonths('proposal.duration'))
       ->select('project.id')
       ->get();
```

But it didn't work. The problem is when I give scalar to `subMonths()`, it works, but it doesn't work with `propsal.duration`.

So how can I do that?

Comment: Try `->where('project.started_at', '>=', DB::raw('now() - interval proposal.duration month')`

Comment: @PaulSpiegel Many thanks, it works. Can I do it purely with the query builder without using raw() to inject strings in the query?

Comment: I don't think so. Every time you want to use an SQL expression like `DATE_ADD`, `DATE_SUB` or `x - interval n ..` you will need `DB::raw()`. There might be exceptions for very common expressions, but I don't know one that you can use for this case.

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative solution, use `DB::raw()` to inject the expression into the query as a string:

```
$proj= DB::table('proposal')
       ->join('project', 'proposal.id', '=', 'project.id')
       ->where(DB::raw('date_add(project.started_at, interval proposal.duration month) >= now()'))
       ->select('project.id')
       ->get();
```